# How to import Twilio for OTP verification in pwa?

Tags: typescript, polymer, progressive-web-apps, twilio-api

I am trying to import Twilio in my Polymer PWA typescript code. But I am getting this error. 
"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '../../node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'".
Do anyone has any idea how to import Twilio in Polymer PWA typescript code?
Thanks in advance.

Below is the snippet I have written showing how I am importing.

```
//import * as twilio from 'twilio';  // Already tried this 
import twilio from 'twilio';
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const client = new twilio.Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using as below.

```
import {twilio} from 'twilio';
```